# c# LinqToLucene index being re created every time

Tags: c#, indexing, linq-to-lucene

I am trying to use LinqToLucene. The index is being saved in the Ram and being regenerated every time the app is being re compiled. This way it takes a few minutes of down time to upload my site's new version. is there a better way of maybe saving the index in a place it doesn't have to be re created every time?